# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 fail to restart properly after installation?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, installation

Why does Ubuntu 16.04 fail to restart properly after installation?

I attempted to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox 5.0.18 on a Windows 7 x64 host. Every time the install completes and I click to restart the system, it freezes on:

> piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade
>   BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr.

[image]

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: I have done so and saw a bunch of unrelated issues. The solutions to the threads that did describe my issue recommended doing an unclean power off, which didn't seem right.

Comment: Its always better to show what you have tried or found searching, this way we do not waste your time giving comments or answers you have already tried of found.

Comment: I see, makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/298290/smbus-bios-error-while-booting-ubuntu-in-virtualbox

There are several options that have worked for people.

I had exactly your scenario. After trying many things I did a reset from the VirtualBox menu and it booted. This was probably just luck.

Answer (score -2):

Try and change the chipset in the settings, this worked for me some time ago when I had this error. Either the IDE controller chipset from PIIX4 -> ICH6 or the MB chipset from PIIX3 -> ICH9 or both. I always to use the newest emulated hardware.

As for why it happens, I cannot tell you.

Comment: How does one change the chipset precisely?  *You should provide specific details on how to do it.*

Comment: I changed both the IDE controller to ICH6 and MB chipset to ICH9 and still get the same hang after clicking to reboot.